# Java CMS GC: can a minor GC occur between final remark and concurrent sweep?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

`Final remark` ensures that all live objects are marked.

`Concurrent sweep`removes garbage.

My assumption is that JVM ensures that minor gc would not run between `final remark` phase and `concurrent sweep` phase otherwise there's another remark to be performed in order to track objects that were just promoted to the old gc. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple look at GC logs can disprove that.

```
271943.846: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
271944.597: [GC (Allocation Failure) 271944.597: [ParNew: 608366K->59226K(613440K), 0.0947925 secs] 1715658K->1185554K(2399176K), 0.0948642 secs] [Times: user=0.45 sys=0.02, real=0.09 secs] 
271945.562: [GC (Allocation Failure) 271945.562: [ParNew: 604570K->52122K(613440K), 0.0845590 secs] 1540676K->1007710K(2399176K), 0.0846276 secs] [Times: user=0.38 sys=0.02, real=0.09 secs] 
271945.694: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.666/1.848 secs] [Times: user=7.65 sys=0.91, real=1.85 secs]
```

As you see, young collections happen between concurrent sweep start and end.

> Is my assumption correct?

You did not consider several possibilities

- young collections suspend the sweep and keep track of promotions so that the sweep threads can skip the promoted set when they resume
- promotion is communicated atomically
- during a concurrent sweep promotion happens into memory regions that won't be touched by the sweep